# spring security unauthorized error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a spring security application with a angular front end. And after a succesful login with username password I see it returns the principal object and session id. But I still get unauthorized errors when I try to access any url eg: "/admin/user/search" Funny thing is it works on my localhost with no problem but get 401 unauthorized error on test server. And it also works via a REST client. But when I login via angular login screen somehow I think cookie is not set correctly or something weird happens

```
http
            .httpBasic().and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/admin/**").access("isAuthenticated()")
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
```

Comment: Is your CsrfHeaderFilter set? I mean will it work if you remove this?

Comment: @farrellmr  tnx I disabled csrf, and it still does not work. It works with a rest client but when user logs in via login screen somehow cookie is not set or something

Comment: Sounds like some network issue - not code - test it with network on the browser

Comment: I have http on server maybe its the problem